# Handle new tabpages and pop ups (GeckoFx)

Tags: c#, geckofx

I searched for this on the net but all examples are messy and hard to understand.
What i want to do:
when browsing in normal browser, sometimes when you click on link then it creates new tab. So I want same in my form. If link want new tab then create that in tab.
same with new pop up. If I click on pop up link then handle it and create in my tab.

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("path to xulrunner");
        GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
        string sUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0";
        GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = sUserAgent;
        myBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }



    private void myBrowser_CreateWindow2(object sender, GeckoCreateWindow2EventArgs e)
    {
    //TabPage tab1 = new TabPage("New WebBrowser");
   // tabBrowser.TabPages.Add(tab1);
    //tab1.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
    }
```